# Sqlite date format in my app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am storing date and time in sqlite as timestamp value e.g.  `1486650099741` when i use it in my code using `setTimeinMillis` for `GregorianCalendar` it converts perfectly. However when i try to year for the same time (in millis) using `strftime ('%Y',datetimestamp)` in sqlite it gives me weird results (year is shown as 1698 and not 2017)

is it something to do with the epoch (used by sqlite) ?

Comment: Yes it worked - i had tried using`unixepoch` but was missing the /1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this `select strftime('%Y', datetimestamp/ 1000, 'unixepoch');`